# Does a base class with the metadata [Bindable] keyword automatically extends EventDispatcher?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, extends, bindable

I'm encountering something a bit bizarre, but maybe someone else came across this before.

I've got a base class, that doesn't extend anything. Let's call it...

```
public class FooBar {
    //...
}
```

But I want to bind EVERY single one of its exposed properties:

```
[Bindable] public class FooBar {
    public var propertyOne:String;
    public var propertyTwo:String;
}
```

While Debugging / Profiling the class, I'm noticing that each time a property is changed - the instance of **FooBar** is calling "**.dispatchEvent()**" on it. But my class doesn't extend **EventDispatcher**.

What gives?

Does this mean, at compile time, my class automatically extends **EventDispatcher** or some other class with the ability to dispatch events? How could I listen to the **PropertyChangeEvent** if my class doesn't have the "**addEventListener**" method declared in it?

Comment: Never noticed this, interesting!

Comment: A bit of a discovery update: actually, all the methods declared in the IEventDispatcher interface are available to that class. The code will compile fine, I just gave it a try. Another developer encountered this same mysterious background activity while making his own calls to "dispatchEvent()" in his Bindable class. Technically, that would mean that only one property or Getter/Setter needs to be declared [Bindable] to cause the class to implement IEventDispatcher, not necessarily the entire class.

Comment: And here's the source of the above mentionned developer who found this too: http://old.nabble.com/-Bindable--and-dispatchEvent-td13765582.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `[Bindable]` metadata the Flex compiler generates a lot of code for you. If you want to know what happens exactly take a look at the answers to [What does the Flex [Bindable] tag do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435527/what-does-the-flex-bindable-tag-do) and the links that are posted there.

To answer your question: No, your class doesn't extend `EventDispatcher`. However, the compiler changes your class so that it will implement the `IEventDispatcher` interface. The generated implemenation of that interface uses an instance of `EventDispatcher`.

Comment: After looking at that old.nabble.com thread (posted in the comments in my question above), the IEventDispatcher interface was my second guess. Thanks to confirm that and providing some resources :)

Comment: Just going to post this here to eliminate some clicks in case someone wants to view the slides directly, explaining the generated code: http://www.slideshare.net/michael.labriola/diving-in-the-flex-data-binding-waters-presentation?src=embed